# Scala strings - how to change lines

Tags: string, scala

I'm trying to create an informative report according to results.
I currently have a .foreach loop iterating over a list, and writes the report.

The code looks like:

```
result.foreach {
    tupleResult =>
      tupleResult._3 match {
        case "FirstTest" =>
          language1 = createReport(tupleResult)
        case "SecondTest" =>
          language2 = createReport(tupleResult)
        case "ThirdTest" =>
          language3 = createReport(tupleResult)
      }
      finalReport = ""
  }
```

Each "createReport" is a method which creates a one line String into the relevant language var.
I want each iteration to add a different line in the "finalReport" string.

Example of "finalReport":

```
Report consists of the following:
1) language1
2) language2
3) language3
```

The question is how to create the different variables as different lines of the same "finalReport" string.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Do you want something like: `finalReport += createReport(...) + "\n"` ?

Comment: It seems like your understood my meaning. i want an ordered list, where each language variable is added to the former in a new line. is the correct way something like this: finalReport = language + "\n" ?

Comment: If you want to overwrite what was in finalReport.

Comment: finalReport += language "\n" doesn't work. it write the \n as part of the string rather than adding a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more idiomatic scala way to do it would be to not do several things at once and also mutate state, but instead see it as separate operations/expressions. Something like this for example:

```
val sortedResults = result.sortBy(_._3 match {
  case "FirstTest" => 1
  case "SecondTest" => 2
  case "ThirdTest" => 3
})

val reportLines = sortedResults.map(result => createReport(result._3))

val finalReport = reportLines.mkString("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Associating an ordering to the test strings may prove a solution, for instance like this,

```
val ord = Array("FirstTest","SecondTest","ThirdTest").zipWithIndex.toMap
```

Then we can generate the parts of the report, and finally sort them by the defined ordering,

```
val finalReport = result.map { tRes => (ord.get(tRes._3), createReport(tRes)) }
  .sortBy(_._1)
  .map(_._2)
  .mkString("\n")
```